# Separate objects in RVT hierarchy by model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am testing out running an SVF2 translation of linked .rvt files. For both a [source file packaged as a zip](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/) and a [source file that contains references](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-containing-xref/), the object hierarchy of my translation is not grouped per linked model. Instead all of the objects in all of the models are in one top-level `objects` array.

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "objects",
    "objects": [
      {
        "objectid": 1,
        "objects": [
          // All objects from the linked models are in here
        ]
        "name": "Model"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible for the translation to split the objects apart by model? On my end I would like to filter the objects on a per-model basis if possible. The only workaround I can think of is to run a separate translation for each model, but that will incur additional costs. Something like this is what I'm hoping to see in the hierarchy:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "objects",
    "objects": [
      {
        "objectid": 1,
        "objects": [
          // Objects from model 1
        ]
        "name": "Model 1"
      },
      {
        "objectid": 2,
        "objects": [
          // Objects from linked model 2
        ]
        "name": "Model 2"
      },
      {
        "objectid": 3,
        "objects": [
          // Objects from linked model 3
        ]
        "name": "Model 3"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very good point. Unfortunately, I'm afraid it is not possible to configure the Model Derivative service translation to restructure the hierarchy like this. We will need to submit a feature request with the engineering team to see if this could be supported.

Comment: In the meantime, if you are the one authoring the Revit models, would it perhaps help to create a separate 3D view for each of the linked models? That way you would only be charged for a single translation, and that translation would generate multiple viewables with their own scene hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks for the help Petr. We don't have a guarantee that we'll be able to access the Revit model to build out separate 3D views. For now we're ok to run separate translations per linked model, but I'm definitely interested in having this as a new feature.